# Who redirect ports on Windows to access http container?

Tags: docker, windows

When we use Linux, Docker can create a rule using iptables to do a port redirection to connect in the http of a container.

When we use Windows, how does this work?

Answer (score 3):

it uses the Hyper-V Virtual Switch (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-networking)